# Yii2: configure yii\web\ViewAction::$viewPrefix

Tags: php, yii2

I want to change default directory ("*pages*") of static pages views, using *yii\web\ViewAction*. [Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#rendering-static-pages) says:

> You may configure yii\web\ViewAction::$viewPrefix to change the
> directory for searching these views.

Question: **where and how** need I to change this property? I tried to do it in controller:

```
use yii\web\ViewAction;
...
public function actions()
{
    (new ViewAction)->viewPrefix = ''; //wanted to do it just as '@app/views/site/', without any subdirectory ('pages' or others)
    return [
        'stat' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
        ],
    ];
}
```

But no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `viewPrefix` to *null*

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'stat' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
            'viewPrefix' => null,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Right, I have seen it already [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#standalone-actions), exactly what I need. Thanks!